# Не получаеться выводить данные которые вводил через админ панель

Tags: html, python, django, bootstrap

Вообщем то проблема в том что на картинке которой вы видете в таблице должны появляться данные которые я запалняю в админ панели

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

product.html тут нужно выводить все данные в таблицу

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}

{% block content %}


    <div class="row centered">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
              <p><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ product.image.url }}"/></p>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
               <h2> {{product.story|safe|linebreaks}} </h2>

          </div>
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Название</th>
                <th scope="col">Продолжительность</th>
                <th scope="col">Языки</th>
                <th scope="col">Требования</th>
                <th scope="col">Места на диске</th>
                <th scope="col">Требования VM</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
           <tbody>
             <tr>
               <td><h4> {{product.title}} </h4></td>
               <td><h4> {{product.time}} </h4></td>
               <td><h4> {{product.langueges}} </h4></td>
               <td><h4> {{product.demand}} </h4></td>
               <td><h4> {{product.memory}} </h4></td>
               <td><h4> {{product.VirtualM}} </h4></td>
             </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

products.html а здесь показываеться лист всех товаров

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% for product in object_list  %}


        <div class="panel panel-default" id="next-block">
          <div class="panel-heading">
                  <p><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ product.preview.url }}"/></p>

          </div>

          <div class="panel-body">
              <a href="/shop/{{product.id}}"> <h1> {{product.title}} </h1> </a>
              <a href="/shop/{{product.id}}"> <h5> {{product.shortStory}} </h5> </a>
          </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.db import models
from django import forms

# Create your models here.

class Products(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    shortStory=models.TextField(default='')
    story = models.TextField(default='')
    preview = models.ImageField(upload_to='')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='')
    time= models.TimeField()
    langueges= models.TextField(default='')
    demand= models.TextField(default='')
    memory= models.TextField(default='')
    VirtualM= models.TextField(default='')



    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from . models import Products

urlpatterns=[
    path('', ListView.as_view(queryset=Products.objects.all(),template_name="shop/products.html")),
    path('<int:pk>/', DetailView.as_view(model=Products, template_name="shop/product.html"))
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py

```
from django.views import generic

from .models import Products


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = "shop/products.html"
    context_object_name = 'products_list'


    def get_queryset(self ):
        return Products.objects.all()
```

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я воспроизвёл Ваш проект. Вы должны использовать следующий код:

```html
...
<td><h4> {{object.title}} </h4></td>
<td><h4> {{object.time}} </h4></td>
...
```

В файле urls.py Вы не указали имя объекту, который будет передаваться в шаблон, поэтому Django использовал "object".

Comment: Все, я наконец-то понял что там в коде происходит)